How I can hide the website technology from Browsers extension like Wapplyzer?
I have developed a website in WordPress and now want to hide the technologies from browser extension to reveal the tech stack to prevent from hackers.
I have tried to add expose_php = off in PHP.ini but its no worked
Added following code into .htaccess file
# Make PHP code look like other code types AddType application/x-httpd-php .asp .py .pl
but its not worked. I have attached the screenshot.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance
expose_php = off in PHP.ini
Added following code into .htaccess file
# Make PHP code look like other code types AddType application/x-httpd-php .asp .py .pl

PHP itself does not expose its technical stack - except for you allow phpinfo or use display_errors. But Wordpress templates are so common, that simply the generated HTML has a recognizable signature you can guess.

Yes, Want to hide PHP and set the expose_php = off and display_errors = Off in PHP.ini file but still showing this.

I don't think that obfuscation helps much. When I look at the logs of my various websites, I see WordPress attacks in all of them, even if they use a completely different technology. The bots are simply trying to exploit a security hole.

expose_php = off just removes the X-Powered-By header. It will take more than that to avoid hackers.

@Wiimm what solution we can apply?

@Olivier Yes I agree but what other solution do you prefer to apply?

@Rajeev I have no solution for it. After analyzing the logs,  I have implemented a special login protection: The login is only possible from the internal company net, or after knocking (special software). But this don't help for faulty WP extensions.

Security through obscurity is not secure.
If your code (or libraries your code depends on) has vulnerabilities that than be exploited, hackers will find them.

By default PHP uses a cookie with name PHPSESSID (wordpress_ in wordpress). This is one of detection items and obviously you should change it before setting a session in Wordpress!(need hard code change) Also you should remove .php from end of urls. Check the Wappalyzer site for more info :
https://www.wappalyzer.com/articles/how-to-hide-technologies-from-wappalyzer/

This has been already tried but if I change the PHPSESSID from ini file this will might be create the issues in future

WordPress doesn’t use this session id stuff in php. If you’re seeing in in a WordPress page, the site is misconfigured.

Thanks for your answer but after doing long research, I have not found any solution so I have applied some extra security layers by writing the code into htaccess file
